# Printer Drivers installed to Windows 10 in Chinese, How can I change it to English?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printer, language, system-preferences

Last weekend I switched out an old pc running Windows Vista with a new one running Windows 10. Our office shares a printer through this computer, so, I needed to reinstall and share that printer (Canon ImageCLASS MF3240) through this new computer.  After hours of searching for drivers that would work and more time spent trying to install them I I figured I had it!

I showed up this morning to find out that all of our printer preferences are in Chinese! I can't find any setting/properties to change this.  All of our network language settings are set to English (every computer is set to English, but preferences display in Chinese across them all).  My bet is that the drivers were in Chinese. Is there any way possible I can change this?

During driver installation, I was never given the option (any option) to set a language, the drivers just installed in the background.

Here I've attached a [Screenshot of Printer Preferances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0H61.png)

I will keep tinkering, in the meantime, if you have a solution I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You'll need to uninstall the drivers, and reinstall the English version, the drivers come in separate installers for languages.  Do you still have the downloaded file?  The end of the file should have a 2 letter code for the language, like this: MF3240_MFDrivers_W64_us_EN.exe. Yours probably has CN. https://www.canondriversoftware.com/canon-imageclass-mf3240-driver/

Comment: Okay! My driver downloads ended in ZH... (Chinese). I used the drivers from your link and they worked perfectly.  However, my printer now displays in the device manager as working, but it does not display in "Devices & Printers"...

Comment: I'd try adding it again via the printers & scanners wizard.  Or, if it's a shared printer on the network, just open it via \\computername\ in Explorer and install the printer from the window showing \\computername's shares.

Comment: Turns out it was there, it was just nexted under the fax machine...  Your solution worked, preferences our in English!!

Comment: I lied. Scratch that previous comment.  Preferences appear in English on the host pc but still appear in Chinese when I add shared printer to another computer.

Comment: When I try to access printer preferences from control panel Windows shots an error: "Function address 0x671290c4 caused a protection fault..."  But I can access these preferences in Chinese from a document like an html file.

Comment: You may need to completely remove the Chinese driver from the clients. First delete the printer. Then click on any other printer and select "Print Server Properties" from the menu that pops up. Click the Drivers tab and remove all instances of the printer from the list.

Comment: I deleted the printer from Control Panel and then removed the drivers on each computer via "Print Server Properties".  I reinstalled the printer to the host and shared it again to the network.  Everything is working perfectly and in English, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my comment worked, I'll give it here again as an answer, for wheel58m to accept.

You may need to completely remove the Chinese driver from the clients. First delete the printer. Then click on any other printer and select "Print Server Properties" from the menu that pops up. Click the Drivers tab and remove all instances of the printer from the list.

Then install the English driver.